# Join 3 tables and add a column with cumulative precentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cumulative-sum

I have 3 tables that I inner join with each other. I add a column that count the partcode for the combined 3 tables. I also want to

add a column with the cumulative procent values of the count column. See below the 3 tables and the result of the query.

```
Table Test1

 Issue  Code 

 1      11   
 2      12   
 3      13   
 4      14   
 5      15   
 6      16   
 7      17   

Table Test2

 Issue  Code

 1      11   
 2      12   
 4      14   
 5      15   
 6      16




Table Test3

 Code   PartCode

 11     A11      
 12     A12      
 13     A12      
 14     A11      
 15     A11      
 16     A16      
 17     A11
```

The next code give the result as below.

```
SELECT T3.PartCode,
       COUNT(T3.PartCode) AS Number    
FROM Test1 T1 INNER JOIN Test2 T2 ON T1.Issue=T2.Issue   
              INNER JOIN Test3 T3 ON T2.Code=T3.Code    
GROUP BY T3.PartCode   
ORDER BY T3.PartCode
```

Result:

```
PartCode  Number  

 A11       3      
 A12       1      
 A16       1
```

Now I want to add the cumulative column. Which give then the table below as result.
How can I create this column with the cumulative precentage of total.

```
Wanted result:
 PartCode  Number  Cumulative precentage 

 A11       3        60                   
 A12       1        80                   
 A16       1       100
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using a SQL Server

Comment: Windowed sets using the over syntax.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: We use the version SQL server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DBMS supports window functions:

```
select ..., sum(100.0*number) over (order by  T3.PartCode) / sum(number) over () as Cumulative_percentage
from ...
```

Edit: elaborated the answer

```
select partcode
     , nbr
     , 100.0*sum(nbr) over (order by partcode) / sum(nbr) over ()
from (
    SELECT T3.PartCode
        , COUNT(*) as nbr
    FROM Test1 T1 
    JOIN Test2 T2 
        ON T1.Issue=T2.Issue   
    JOIN Test3 T3 
        ON T2.Code=T3.Code    
    GROUP BY T3.PartCode  
) as x
ORDER BY PartCode ;
```

Edit updated according to comment:

```
select partcode
     , Description
     , nbr
     , 100.0*sum(nbr) over (order by nbr desc
                                   , partcode) / sum(nbr) over () 
        as Cum_Percentage
from (
    SELECT T3.PartCode
        , T3.Description
        , COUNT(*) as nbr
    FROM Test1 T1 
    JOIN Test2 T2 
        ON T1.Issue=T2.Issue   
    JOIN Test3 T3 
        ON T2.Code=T3.Code    
    GROUP BY T3.PartCode, T3.Description  
) as x
ORDER BY nbr desc;
```

Comment: When I use number by the website sqlfiddle then the column 'number' is unknown. See sqlfiddle example [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ebeb/7)

Comment: number is the counted value, I'll update the answer. I assume that you created the fiddle for mysql by mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did some changes to the code and I have now an issue with the Cum_percentage column.
The column nbr must be sort in a descending order. The results in Cum_Percentage are mostly correct, but when nbr has range of 2, 2, 1 then the results in the Cum_Percentage are not correct. The result of column Cum_Percentage is 80, 80, 100 and must be 40, 80, 100. See my changes in the sqlfiddle example [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e29cd/10)

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. There is a draw between two of the nbr. If partcode is unique you can add that to the order by clause like: `  100.0*sum(nbr) over (order by nbr desc, partcode) / sum(nbr) over () as Cum_Percentage` If you prefer one to be sorted before the other in case of a draw, use asc (default) or desc in the same way as with nbr

Comment: Thanks for your help. This was the total complete solution!